# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working in this Angular project where user submits a comment form, and the new comment is added to the comments that's already posted. Here is my code.

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Page){
$scope.product = {};
$scope.review = {};
$scope.comments = {};

routeparm = $routeParams.param;

$scope.review = function(){
    var review_box = $scope.review_form.review_box;

    $http.post('./comment.php', {
        comment : review_box,
        code: routeparm
    })

    .success(function(data){
            $scope.comments.push(data.comments);
            $scope.review.review_box = '';
    })

    .error(function(data){
        $scope.has_error = true;
        $scope.error_message = data;
    })

};
```

However when I try to add a comment I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I've defined an empty $scope.comments = {}; so why am I getting this error? And how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: you cannot use push for json object. But this will work $scope.comments = [ ];  if you initialize this as array.

Comment: First of all, why `push` is being using on an object ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comments you have declared is an Object. Just change your declaration to an array ,

**From:**

```
$scope.comments = {};
```

**To:**

```
$scope.comments = [];
```

**EDIT:**
If you need to Push new Object, You need to make your Comments as Array of Object like this and push the new Object

```
$scope.comments = { 
    1: {name:'',review:'',comment:'',uptime:'',gravatar:''}
}

 $scope.comments.push({name:'rukshi', review:'test comment',comment:'yet another comment',uptime:'',gravatar:''});
```

Comment: Still getting the error, the json data looks like this {"comments":{"name":"rukshi","review":"test comment","uptime":1428553143000,"gravatar":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/ca1a69438a32fd2aa60806b90a960753?s=48"},"error":{"has_error":false}}

Comment: Yes, there was another problem in the part of the code that haven't posted which sets $scope.comments to undefined, fix that and with your fix everything works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Page){
  $scope.product = {};
  $scope.review = {};
  $scope.comments = [];

  routeparm = $routeParams.param;

  $scope.review = function(){
  var review_box = $scope.review_form.review_box;

$http.post('./comment.php', {
    comment : review_box,
    code: routeparm
}).success(function(data){
        $scope.comments.push(data.comments);
        $scope.review.review_box = '';
}).error(function(data){
    $scope.has_error = true;
    $scope.error_message = data;
})

};
```